# BeautifulSoup a.['href'] exception handling

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using bs4 and scraping links, in some cases in the loop `there is no <a href=""> tag`.

So in that case I want to input the `text` attribute of the element.

my sample code,

```
base_url = "http://example.com"

abc = base_url + str(tds.a['href']) if tds.a['href'] else tds.text
```

Exception is thrown

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

This is how my `td` element looks like:

```
<td nowrap=""><font face="Arial" size="1"><a href="view_document?docurl=http://www.envirostor.dtsc.ca.gov/public/deliverable_documents/6382679581/Recorded%20LUC%2010%2D14%2D2010%2Epdf" target="6382679581">[VIEW COVENANT]</a> </font></td>"
```

How to solve this??

Ps. using Python 3 and Bs4

Comment: Presumably here either `tds` or `tds.a` is `None`. You'll want to check that instead `tds.a['href'] if tds.a else 'some default'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the has_attr() method in BS4:

```
abc = base_url + str(tds.a['href']) if tds.has_attr('href') else tds.text
```

Comment: Or just use `tds.text` as the default, ie: `abc = base_url + tds.a.get('href', tds.text)`

Comment: Yes, that's cleaner.

Comment: True, but it still won't solve the problem - "in some cases in the loop there is no `<a href="">` tag". Perhaps check if there is an 'a' tag?

Comment: @t.m.adam your solution looks much cleaner. thank you

Answer (score 1):

In Python, it is always [**EAFP**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python) (Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission).

If the `a` tag doesn't have the `href` attribute, `tds.a['href']` will raise a `KeyError`.
If the `td` tag doesn't have the `a` tag, `tds.a['href']` will raise a `TypeError` as shown in the question.

So, using the **EAFP** principle:

```
base_url = "http://example.com"
try:
    abc = base_url + tds.a['href']
except (KeyError, TypeError):
    abc = base_url + tds.text
```